# need to press flatlist child for 2/3 second to actually travel to link

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, onpress

## What is happening :

I have a flatlist rendering a component with onPress inside. It is doing the job but i need to press the flatlist for about two or three second so that the onPress fire which is ruining the user experience.

## I have tryed :

- replacing onPress with onPressOut which fire instantly everytime you come near the button (result in button press by accident)
- moving onPress in the renderItem of the flatlist (not in the component called)

**the flatlist :**

`travelToOperation = (papi) => {
    this.props.link.navigate('Operation', { papi: papi });
}`

```
<FlatList
      style={styles.collaboratorList}
      data={latestOperation.stack}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.NUMERO}
      maxToRenderPerBatch={1}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <LastOperation data={item} 
       operationDetail={this.travelToOperation} />
      }
 />
```

**lastOperation component :**

`<TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={() => this.props.operationDetail(this.props.data)}>
      <View>//somestuff </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>`

## What i want :

Just the basic result of onPress (as in all the other onPress i do in the app) which is a basic click

Thanks for any suggestions, i'm pretty new to react-native so i can assume it's some basic stuff...

Comment: Is this on a real device or in emulator simulator? It might be bad performance in the emulator/simulator and perhaps running the app on a real device will solve the issue.

Comment: No if i click then wait it does nothing. If i want to trigger the onPress i need to keep my finger on the button (as i said 2/3s) and then release. onPress trigger when i release (as it is supposed to)

Comment: Yes i'm using a real device. To check if it is a latency issue i tryed to compile the app in production mode. More than that when i use onPressOut it fires immediately so it's possible to do so i'm just doing something wrong but can't put my finger on it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this problem because of property

`maxToRenderPerBatch={1}`

As documentation says CONS from this property is blocking others process.

> Pros: Setting a bigger number means less visual blank areas when scrolling (increases the fill rate).
>
> **Cons: More items per batch means longer periods of JavaScript execution potentially blocking other event processing, like presses, hurting responsiveness.**

You must remove this prop to get UI render asynchronous.

If this help you please like it.

Comment: Thanks for you're answer. This was indeed the issue and i solved it without even understand why it did not worked. 
I was using maxToRenderPerBatch to optimize the rendering of my flatlist as it is pretty long and therefore very long to render.
Recently i changed  this:
```import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';```
to this :
```import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';```
and it solved the issue as the new one must fix this con.
Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

What worked : replacing Touchable from react-native with

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the behavior the same using "TouchableHighlight", "TouchableOpacity" instead of "TouchableWithoutFeedback"?
BTW you get the best user experience using "https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler".
Why do you use "TouchableWithoutFeedback"?

Comment: Yes it is the same behavior (apart from the obvious click animation as it is supposed to be). Btw the click animation is done at the time i wish it would travel (without delay even when i don't do a long press). I did not knew the gesture handler i'll have a look at it

Comment: i check react native gesture handler and as i use expo the installation is uselessly complicated (i would need to use special subclasses of ReactRootView for react native navigation and gesture handler)

Comment: if the behavior is the  same with TouchableHighlight/TouchableOpacity then i guess you have a performance problem with FlatList. Have a look how many times the render function of your FlatList is called.